# Repair setup project throws Error 1001: "The specified service already exists"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, setup-project, repair

The repair function for a setup project is basically a re-install, but because of my custom Install/Commit/Rollback/Uninstall action to manage a Windows service, my repair fails because the service already exists when the repair function is called.

The setup project should first remove the service before repairing it. I am already injecting custom actions via `using System.Configuration.Install`, so it should be possible.

How do I instruct the repair function to first remove the service?

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking for a quick solution, then you can always delete the service manually in the custom action.

Create a new process to the call the "sc.exe" with the parameters as below:

```
sc.exe delete [service name]
```

of course, you will require some exception handling in here to check if the service already exists or not.